# Auto select the first index in a sparks List control in flex4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a spark List control. It has a dataProvider that shows reply from twitter search.

I have created a function for change handler like this:

```
protected function list_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
{
    ta.text = coverflow.selectedItem.title;
}
```

So, whenever I select each of the items in the List, I will see the message(ta.text)
but now, instead of me manually clicking the first time, I want it to automatically click/select the first item and see the first message(ta.text)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the **[requireSelection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ListBase.html#requireSelection)** property to **true** on the list control

```
<s:List id="myList" dataProvider="{myDataProvider}" requireSelection="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in thinking about this, you probably need to subclass the list and override the dataProvider setter.

```
override public function set dataProvider(data:*) : void {
  super._dataProvider = data;
  // This will be an ArrayCollection or XMLListCollection, so will have a length
  if (data && data.length > 0) {
    this.selectedIndex = 0;
    invalidateDisplayList();
  }
}
```

Comment: No need for subclassing unless he wants the same behavior in more than one place.

Answer (score 0):

How about to try this solution? :)

Your list control also has event name `creationComplete` (similar to `change` event). Try to select your first item with this:

```
protected function list1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    if(event.target.dataProvider != null )
    {
        (event.target as List).selectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

You may not need to convert `event.target` to `List`. but it may help you access code completion while you are coding.

Comment: This will fail if the dataProvider is null at creationComplete.

Comment: Thank, Robusto. I improved my answer follow your mention.

Comment: I'd also recommend writing your assignment as `List(event.target).selectedIndex = 0;`  That way your intellisense will work and the syntax checker won't put up a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Set the dataProvider of the list, set the selected item, and then either call your handler function directly with a null parameter, or make the list dispatch an indexChanged event so that your handler function gets executed.